# Authorize swagger ui with django

Tags: django, django-rest-framework, swagger

i'm writing a REST API with django-rest-framework and oauth2 for authentication purpose.

I'm also using django-rest-swagger to document my APIs but i have a problem with the authorization in the Swagger UI. Pratically i don't understand how i may define the authorizationUrl parameter, these are the settings i'm using:

```
SWAGGER_SETTINGS = {
'USE_SESSION_AUTH': False,
'APIS_SORTER': 'alpha',
'SECURITY_DEFINITIONS': {
    'oauth2': {
        'type': 'oauth2',
        'description': 'Personal API Key authorization',
        'name': 'Token',
        'in': 'header',
        'flow': 'implicit',
        'authorizationUrl': 'http://localhost:8000/api/user/login'
    }
}}
```

The question is: How must i define a page where the user enter his username and password to see all the documentations APIs?

Thanks in advance